# Use emacs to copy kill-ring to window/buffer based on position

Tags: emacs, position

This may be too involved.
Considering:
In emacs in r-mode or lisp mode (etc) information can be sent directly (copied, pasted, evaluated) from one buffer to the the R or Lisp interpreter.

I typically configure an emacs session to have 3 windows - a large horizontal window on top and two windows beneath it. (How) could I configure, which keys/ commands might I use to send the kill-ring to the last cursor position of the top window / buffer?

The buffer / window will not always necessarily have the same contents/file. (How) could I name it upon initialization?
Similar to C-X, C-B or C-X, B how might I specify which of the three window positions to go to (based on position)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [window-at](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Coordinates-and-Windows.html).  For example,

```
(defun yank-into-top-window (&optional arg)
  (interactive "*P")
  (with-selected-window (window-at 0 0)
    (yank arg)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to have to write lisp code to do this effectively.  Basically, you'd want a minor mode that sets up the two subwindows -- which isn't hard, it happens in compile mode from `M-x compile` -- and then make special keybindings for the keys you want to use.